# Adding link on a transparent div with background image

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a transparency on, and I need to put a link on top of the transparency, but neither the solid color or the link seems to work, I have been trying different things like putting the link inside a div, or even making the image likeable and just adding the text on top but I can't make it work.
any ideas?

```css
.skewed {
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: white;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  min-height: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 5%;
}


.skewed:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.skewed a {
    padding: 50%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4 skewed" style="background-image: url(https://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/10-dithering-opt.jpg);">
            <a href="" class="link">link</a>
          </div>
            
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a z-index issue. The pseudo element is positioned on top of the link, so the link isn't clickable. Add `z-index: -1` to `.skewed:after`

```css
.skewed {
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: white;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  min-height: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 5%;
}


.skewed:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: -1;
}

.skewed a {
    padding: 50%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4 skewed" style="background-image: url(https://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/10-dithering-opt.jpg);">
            <a href="" class="link">link</a>
          </div>
            
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess I was a little late to get my answer posted, but my solution is slightly different, so here's an alternative fix. Yes, you're issue is related to the z-index. In my opinion, your div is unnecessary, so I removed it's properties under the anchor tag. I also added a line-height of 350px to center the text. Obviously, that's only effective if your text is contained to a single line, so you can remove that property, if you don't find it helpful.

```
a{
  font-size: 5em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 350px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(https://www.smashingmagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/10-dithering-opt.jpg);
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  min-height: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 5%;
}
a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <a href="" class="link">link</a>            
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this :)